# $(document).ready Javascript in Angular project code works on Edge but not chrome or firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, google-chrome

I added a file named 'custom.min.js' in my assets folder in my Angular project that has only this code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".collapse-link").on("click", function() {

      console.log("hhahahaah")
      var a = $(this).closest(".x_panel"),
        b = $(this).find("i"),
        c = a.find(".x_content");
      a.attr("style") ? c.slideToggle(200, function() {
          a.removeAttr("style")
        }) : (c.slideToggle(200),
          a.css("height", "auto")),
        b.toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down")
      return false
    }),
    $(".close-link").click(function() {
      var a = $(this).closest(".x_panel");
      a.remove()
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
  <li><a class="collapse-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#contenu"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This code works fine on Edge but doesn't  on Chrome or Firefox

Comment: Sorry for the 'console.log("hhahahaah")' that's how i debug

Answer (score 0):

declare $ variable in component.ts after import statement.
**`declare var $: any;`**

and add your jquery code in  `ngOnInit(){}` like below
and replace `function` keywords with arrow function `()=>`

```
$(document).ready(()=> {
    $(".collapse-link").on("click", ()=> {
      console.log("hhahahaah")
      var a = $(this).closest(".x_panel")
        , b = $(this).find("i")
        , c = a.find(".x_content");
      a.attr("style") ? c.slideToggle(200, ()=> {
          a.removeAttr("style")
      }) : (c.slideToggle(200),
      a.css("height", "auto")),
      b.toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down")
  return false}),
  $(".close-link").click(()=> {
      var a = $(this).closest(".x_panel");
      a.remove()
  })
  });
```

Comment: That worked once , the moment i reloaded the page it stopped working again.

Comment: can you create http://stackblitz.com so i can help you better